# "participant listing options" how to add another option with more fields

Tags: civievent

The existing options are 
name only
name and email
name, status and register date

How do i add an option with more fields eg role, phone etc is it a template somewhere?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is how i would do

1. Create Extension
2. Add install code via Managed hook to install new option value for option group 'participant_listing'

snippet:

```
{
  "option_group_id": "participant_listing",
  "label": "Your Name",
  "value": "4",
  "name": "Your Name",
  "description": "CRM_Event_Page_ParticipantListing_YOURNAME",
  "is_active": "1"
}
```

3. Copy CRM/Event/Page/ParticipantListing/NameStatusAndDate.php and CRM/Event/Page/ParticipantListing/NameStatusAndDate.tpl into your extension folder and rename the files to YOURNAME.php and YOURNAME.tpl resp.
4. Change the code(in YOURNAME.php) in respective function like run(), preProcess(), orderBY() as per your need and you can also modify the tpl file as per your needs.
5. Test! Test! Test!

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you Pradeep for that very detailed answer. All a bit beyond my skill level I'm afraid. Are you able to give me an idea of how many hours work this would be for a developer and the best way to find a developer? Many thanks for you help

Comment: You can email me at pradpnayak [at] gmail [dot] com.